# Not enough arguments (missing: "key"). in laravel php artisan cache:forget

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-cache

When i try to remove my all cache file from laravel 5.5 project i got some error during run this command

> php artisan cache:forget

**Not enough arguments (missing: "key").**

Comment: Did you execute this command `php artisan key:generate`?

Answer (score 2):

use command `php artisan cache:forget -h` for see list Arguments and options.

**this is list agruments and option of cache:forget command larvel 5.4**

```
Arguments:
  key                   The key to remove
  store                 The store to remove the key from

Options:
  -h, --help            Display this help message
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
      --env[=ENV]       The environment the command should run under
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
```

**if you want remove all cache file you can run this command**

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

**and see more artisan command**

```
php artisan list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

after key generate with this command:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Answer (score 0):

For removing a entire Cache you can use `Cache::flush();`

For removing a key from Cache u can use `Cache::forget('key')` programmatically.

You can also use `artisan console`

```
php artisan cache:forget key="yourkey"
```

Hope this helps